# ExtJS itemselector with search/filter option

Tags: extjs4, multi-select, itemselector

I am looking for a ExtJS itemselector with search/filter option. Is there a existing plugin for this or any ideas to implement it? Since itemselector internally uses Multiselect, do I need to implement my own version on Multiselect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The multiselect extension has an option for configuring the tbar (Top bar) property. I used the following code to configure the "toField" of itemselector:

```
 tbar : {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                flex: 1,
                dock: 'top',
                items: [
                    'Filter:',
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield', 
                        fieldStyle: 'text-align: left;',                            
                        enableKeyEvents: true,
                        listeners: {
                            scope: this,
                            change : function(field, newValue, oldValue, options) {                                 
                                var toStore = this.toField.boundList.getStore();                                    
                                toStore.clearFilter();
                                if (String(newValue).trim() != "")
                                {
                                    toStore.filterBy(function(rec, id){
                                        return this.filterFunc(rec, newValue);  
                                    }, this);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

And my filterFunc is :

```
filterFunc: function(rec, filter)
{        
    var value = rec.get(this.displayField);

    if (this.filterIgnoreCase) value = value.toLocaleUpperCase();
    if (this.filterIgnoreCase) filter = filter.toLocaleUpperCase();

    if (Ext.isEmpty(filter)) return true;

    if (this.filterAnyMatch && this.filterWordStart)
    {
        var re_opts = this.filterIgnoreCase ? 'i' : '';
        var re = new RegExp('(^|[\\s\\.!?;"\'\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}])'+Ext.escapeRe(filter), re_opts);
        return re.test(value);
    }
    else if (this.filterAnyMatch)
    {
        var re_opts = this.filterIgnoreCase ? 'i' : '';
        var re = new RegExp(Ext.escapeRe(filter), re_opts);
        return re.test(value);
    }
    else
    {
        var re_opts = this.filterIgnoreCase ? 'i' : '';
        var re = new RegExp('^\s*'+Ext.escapeRe(filter), re_opts);
        return re.test(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked very well for me, but I had to hack the ItemSelector code a bit to get the tbar in there. Is there something I missed that allowed you to get this working without modifying the original ux.form.ItemSelector code?

Comment: @codekoala I cannot recall what I exactly did, I havent used ExtJS for 8 months now. As far as I know, I was on ExtJS 4 and I dont remember doing any special changes to ItemSelector. May be its just version issue.